# Multiplexing a set of signals

Tags: multiplexer

I want to multiplex 8 input lines but have 2 output lines. I'll have two select lines, based on which, the output lines will carry 1st-and-2nd or 3th-and-4th or 5th-and-6th or 7th-and-8th input lines. Is there a component I can directly use for this application or will I have to build this using two separate normal 4 to 1 multiplexers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two-in-one [74LS153](http://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS153.shtml) chip which will do the job for you.

Comment: Sorry made a typo, corrected. It is 153, not 173